# org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes at the startup

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting such error at the startup of my project: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes` 
I uses Spring MVC + Hibernate, for the server I am using Oracle Weblogic 12c.
Here is my pom.xml

```
 <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     <exclusions>
         <!--
      <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion> -->
      <exclusion> 
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      </exclusion> 
     </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
     <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
       <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
       <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring3 MVC Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <!-- 
   <init-param>
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-config.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
    -->
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Here is my controller

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private SessionFactory sf;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

So, when I start my program it will send me to the `index.html` where I have form and could work further with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so honestly I don't know what was the problem, but restarting the IDE and Clean Build help me to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are using different versions in your spring components, try to use the same version of all the spring dependencies